# Neutrino Oscillation and Probability

Tags: resource-recommendations, probability, education, neutrinos, elementary-particles

I am a fresher in a university pursuing physics major. I have been very passionate about neutrinos.

So, I started studying them. But I have realised that, it requires a lot of mathematical physics like operators, matrices, complex numbers etc. So can anybody please tell the prerequisite to study neutrino oscillations.

I also request anybody to guide me, 'How to start approaching the neutrino oscillations study?'

Answer (score 1):

Neutrino Oscillations usually come up in higher-level courses.  Before you can get anywhere near this, you'll need to make sure you understand a lot of other things first.

From a mathematics viewpoint, you'll need to be comfortable with Calculus (integrating and differentiating functions) and Linear algebra (handling vectors and matrices).  Complex numbers are a useful tool to handle anything that oscillates, so you'd need to be familiar with those.

From a physics viewpoint, you'll need to understand a bunch of concepts, such as:

- Quantum mechanics (e.g. you need to know what eigenstates are)
- Scattering theory (very useful in particle physics generally -- this is how we know anything about particles)
- Special relativity (most particle physics works at high velocities, so the classical Schrödinger equation doesn't work)
- Experimental Physics concepts (things like error analysis and measurement techniques that are also very important in particle physics, even if you plan to be a pure theorist)
- Classical Field Theory (if you aim to go deep into QFT and the maths behind Feynman diagrams)

These are just a few pre-requisites I can think of before you can go on to take a course in Particle Physics, and then come across neutrino oscillations.  Basically, you'll need to get through most of a Physics Degree before you can properly study this topic.

Having said all that, I hope I haven't deterred you!  You've got a lot to look forward to if you genuinely like physics, and the rewards at the end are worth it (in my opinion at least).  And of course, if you can understand some popular science stuff on the topic, by all means read about it and grow your interests.

**TL;DR**:  To properly understand the physics of neutrino oscillations, you need a solid baseline in more general physics first.